# Backend C# Loop with SQL Insert issue

Tags: c#, sql, loops, insert

I have a comma delimited textbox and a loop which parses it out and loops to create a series of SQL INSERT statements.  However, only the first SQL INSERT statement in [Message_Bridge] is working.  The foreach statement is working fine the first time through, but subsequent iteration do not INSERT.  No errors are thrown.

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Messages]([Subject], [Body], [Date_Time], [Originator], [Canceled], [Message_Index]) VALUES(@Subject, @Body, GETDATE(), @Originator, 0, 0); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

dataCommand.Parameters.Clear();
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", ComposeSubjectTexbox.Text);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", ComposeBodyTexbox.Text);
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Originator", 506);
var Message_ID = dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();

string[] Recipients = ComposeToTextBox.Text.Split(',');

dataCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Message_Bridge]([Message_ID], [User_ID]) SELECT TOP 1 @Message_ID, [User_ID] FROM [Users] WHERE [User_Name] = @User_Receiver; ";
dataCommand.Parameters.Clear();
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message_ID", Message_ID);
dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@User_Receiver", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

foreach (string User_Receiver in Recipients)
{
    dataCommand.Parameters["@User_Receiver"].Value = User_Receiver;
    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: just to be sure, do all of the values for `User_Receiver` exist in the `Users` table?

Comment: Suggest you to use sql profiler to see whether insert command is executed. If not, try to create new instanst for dataCommand in loop

Comment: When you `.Add` the parameter for `@User_Receiver` try supplying the maximum length as the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that my Split() function was adding a space to the end of each User_Receiver.  This caused only the first INSERT function to work and the subsequent ones to not go thru.  The INSERT-SELECT function was set up correctly but the data I fed into it wasn't correct.  Thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should use [bulkinserter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), it will be quicker and is made for bulk inserting :)

Comment: I tried Initializing he data command inside of the loop, but no effect.  I also explicitly stated the maximum length in the AddWithValue() functions; no effect.  I would like to try bulkinserter, but I know that it's used for transactions where there are 1000's of rows whereas I only have about 10.  Shouldn't what I have work?  Is this a bug?